# Can Cypress wait for lazy loaded components in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, cypress

**What is the best way to wait until Vuejs finished loading all components/finished the rendering, without check the network/other black magic?**

**Scenario**: We are testing our Vuejs2 frontend E2E flows with Cypress. Lately we optimized our common component to be lazy loaded (AKA async components), like

```
Vue.component(
  'some-lazy-component', () => import('./some-lazy-component')
)
```

We saw that a lot of test fails on various errors, like

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is not visible
```

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM
```

**What we tried?**

1. Visibility verification before interaction with the element, like `cy.get(...).should('be.visible')`. Partially worked, element are visible but detached (how can it be?)
2. Clicking with force `cy.click({force: true})`. Partially worked and doesn't seems to be the cleanest solution.
3. Adding a network idle wait, using this library [cypress-network-idle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-network-idle). with `cy.waitForNetworkIdle(1000);` Works most of the time but we have to wait at least 1000ms, and it smells flaky and dirty